# Import csv into excel and specify cell format

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to import multiple csv files into their own tabs in 1 excel workbook. I am having an issue with long number fields being displayed as exponential data and changing the last digit to 0. For example I have a 16 digit account number (1234567890123456) it is being displayed in excel as an exponential number (1.23457E+15). When I look at the actual number in the cell it is (1234567890123450). I assume if I make the column text before I bring it in, it will work, but I'm not sure how to do that. Here is my code.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$excel.visible = $False 
$excel.displayalerts=$False 
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.add()
$sheets = $workbook.sheets
$sheetCount = $Sheets.Count
$mySheet = 1
$mySheetName = "Sheet" + $mySheet
$s1 = $sheets | where {$_.name -eq $mySheetName }
$s1.Activate()
If($sheetCount -gt 1)
{
#Delete other Sheets
$Sheets | ForEach
    {
    $tmpSheetName = $_.Name
    $tmpSheet = $_
    If($tmpSheetName -ne "Sheet1"){$tmpSheet.Delete()}
    }
}
#import csv files
$files = dir -Path $csvDir*.csv
ForEach($file in $files){
If($mySheet -gt 1){$s1 = $workbook.sheets.add()}
$s1.Name = $file.BaseName
$s1.Activate()
$s1Data = Import-Csv $file.FullName 
$s1data | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Clip
$s1.cells.item(1,1).Select()
$s1.Paste()
$mySheet ++
if (test-path $file ) { rm $file }
}

$workbook.SaveAs($excelTMGPath)
$workbook.Close()
$workbook = $null
#$excel.quit() 
while ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($excel)) {}
$excel = $null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

If `$s1` is pointed correctly,

```
$s1.cells.item(1,1).NumberFormat="@"
```

If that does not work, use `NumberFormat` where necessary.  Use the format you prefer.

Change the name of your file extension from .csv to .txt.  Adjust your filename in the code,

```
$files = dir -Path $csvDir*.txt
```

Comment: That throws this error: Property 'NumberFormat' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Powershelltest\FullScript.ps1:line:213 char:28
+ $s1.cells.item(1,1).Select.N <<<< umberFormat="General"

Comment: I still get the property 'NumberFormat' Cannot be found error

Comment: @user3266792 I removed the selection.

Comment: That no longer throws an error, but the field is still coming in as an exponential format where it changes the last digit to a 0. I also tried NumberFormat="text", but that didn't work either.

Comment: @user3266792 Beyond above, I cannot help.  You will have to fidget with the code, perhaps try a Range object or another cell location to test.

Comment: It is only doing the format for cell a1. Do you have a recommendation on how to do it for a specific column or all columns?

Comment: @user3266792 You only told it to do 1,1.

Comment: Thanks for the .Numberformat I was able to get it to work using that on the specific columns where the import was incorrect. Not sure why the question was down voted though...